# How to implement IObjectSafety programmatically in JScript.NET

Tags: .net, jscript, jscript.net

tldr; How to mark a JScript.NET dll as safe for scripting?

Consider this JScript.NET library `(helloworld1.js)`:

```js
package helloworld1{
  class test1 {
    public function test1run(){
      return 'This is a string returned from helloworld1.dll';
    }
  }
}
```

After running it through

`jsc.exe /nologo /t:library helloworld1.js`

and

`regasm /nologo /codebase helloworld1.dll`

I can use it on my local html page with:

```js
var helloworld1 = new ActiveXObject("helloworld1.test1");
alert(helloworld1.test1run());
```

It all works fine and I get an alert with `This is a string returned from helloworld1.dll`.

**Now... I want to get rid of the dreaded IE security warning which pops up every time the ActiveX object is instantiated**:

`An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction?`

I know the way to remove the security warning is to mark the dll as `safe for scripting` and implement `IObjectSafety`.

**I know how to do this in VB6 and VB.NET but how do I go implementing it in JScript.NET?**

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549465/how-to-sign-an-activex-dll-with-a-certificate

Comment: @Erik Philips: I don't think so. As far as I can see, that question is about **signing** a dll with a real certificate, my question involves implementing `IObjectSafety` in JScript.NET.

Comment: You stated `I want to get rid of the dreaded IE security warning which pops up every time the ActiveX object is instantiated`, which requires signing your DLL, which also requires implementing `IObjectSafety`.

Comment: @Erik Philips: I added `programmatically` to the question title. I hope that satisfies you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an extensive research I figured out, as there is absolutely no documentation for IObjectSafety in JScript.NET, I can't implement this interface directly in the code.

I finally settled down with adding the needed registry keys for marking my dll as "Safe for initialization" and "Safe for scripting":

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\[MY_COM_CLASS_GUID]\Implemented Categories\{7DD95801-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\[MY_COM_CLASS_GUID]\Implemented Categories\{7DD95802-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}]
```

I add these keys during my setup routine, when helloworld1.dll is deployed on target machines. It works flawlessly.

Comment: But... but... it's NOT actually safe for scripting? Sigh.

Comment: @x0n: No it's NOT safe. As matter of fact, this is pretty dangerous. Don't try it.