# Map a Network Printer from a web page

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

In short, I have an image map that points to network printers on my floor.  I would like my user to click on given coordinates associated with network printer X.  When they click on this using IE versions 7 thru 9, I would like that printer to be mapped.  If I can (later), I may want to set that as their default printer.

I can do this in many ways using local programs written in WSH/VBS, PowerShell, Batch File, C# Windows apps, but can't seem to perform it as simply as I am stating here via a webpage.

The requirement is it should be very simple for the in-house user. "Click > Yes > yes > done". I can control the browser and all users are on the internal secured network.

Any ideas are most welcomed.
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to do it via a web page.

By default, what can be done via a browser-based application, client-side is limited to prevent malicious developers from crafting websites that alter user's machine configurations.

That said, you COULD craft an [ActiveX control to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229115%28VS.60%29.aspx) (but not via .NET) I think you'd need to use the much older VB6, or C++).  That's a completely different animal than doing it via a web page, and it's not for the faint-of-heart.

You really need a client-side solution.

The closest you could come to a web-based solution in .NET would be to write a client app and deploy it via [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!  I will continue to look

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of doing that is to write a [Signed ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549465/how-to-sign-an-activex-dll-with-a-certificate) (IE Only) which would allow you to perform any action you want.

(technically you could write an unsigned activeX control, but getting around the security certificate issues in IE would most likely be a nightmare)