# ActiveX Certificate

Tags: javascript, html, activex, activexobject

I have found a script that will open excel on a specific sheet through a web page.

I am encountering an issue because every time I try to open it i get an error that says the ActiveX Control is not signed. I need to fix this and not use a workaround like allowing unsigned ActiveX controls because this function will be used on an intranet site for everyone in my office.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Open_Excel_File(path,sheet)
      {

        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        if (!fso.FileExists(path))
          alert("Cannot open file.\nFile '" + path + "' doesn't exist.");

        else
         {
           var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

           if (myApp != null)
             {
               myApp.visible = true;
               Book = myApp.workbooks.open(path);
               var excel_sheet = Book.Worksheets(sheet).Activate;
               myApp.range(f_range).Select;
             }

           else {
             alert ("Cannot open Excel application");
           }
         }
      }
 </script>

 <button onclick="Open_Excel_File('C:\\Users\\sodonnell\\Desktop\\test1.xlsm', 'sheet2');">Rawr</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sign an ActiveX DLL with a Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549465/how-to-sign-an-activex-dll-with-a-certificate)

Comment: @Triby Yes it does thank you so much!